# using d3 transitions with filtering

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I am very new with javascript and I am hoping to receive any guidance I can here - I am currently trying to create a dashboard that will dash data from a csv with 2 filters. One drop down - which is the region, and one slider which is the year.

The data looks something like this:
`Country,Metric1,Metric2,Region,Year`

I set up the graph by the usual svg select data enter append method, but I am currently trying to add smooth transition when a different year was selected (slider moved) with the same region. I have no problem redrawing the graph -

(What I tried without transition)

```
function update_data(year,region) {
    
    //remove old graph
    d3.select("svg").remove();
    // append the svg object to the body of the page
    var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
      .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
             "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
    //Read the data
    d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {
    
      // Add X axis
      var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([1000, 55000])
        .range([ 0, width ]);
      svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5));
    
      // Add Y axis
      var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 300])
        .range([ height, 0]);
      

      var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(['Asia', 'Europe', 'Africa', 'Americas', 'Oceania'])
        .range(['#a8e6cf','#dcedc1', '#ffd3b6', '#ffaaa5','#ff8b94']);


      svg.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5));
      
      //add new data each dot is a country
      svg.append('g')
        .selectAll("dot")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
          .filter(function(d) {
                return +d.year == year && d.region == region;
            })
          .attr("cx", function (d) {
            return x(d.Metric1); } )
          .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(Metric2); } )
          .attr("r", 4)
          .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.region); });    

    });

}
```

What I am trying is to allow smooth transition between the data points, just different year. This is what I tried - I have attached this function to a slider - however when I moved the slider nothing seems to be happening. I thought that since the amount of data points are the same, I just simply need to change the x and y attributes

```
function update_year(year,region) {
        
    //Read the data
    d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {

      svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data)
        .filter(function(d) {
                return +d.year == year && d.region == region;
            })
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
          .attr("cx", function (d) {
            return x(d.Metric1); } )
          .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(Metric2); } )
          .attr("r", 4)
          .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.region); });
    });

}
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated on what I can do. Thank you so much in advance!